# Trouble creating a GIT repository in Bluemix

Tags: git, repository, ibm-cloud

I am having this problem right now while coding on Bluemix:

When I try to create a GIT repository after creating an application on Bluemix, I receive this message error:

"Impossible to connect at IBM DevOps Services. Try later"

Is this problem known to someone?

Thank for answers,

Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

Alessandro, it's standard practice with Bluemix to create a git repository that deploys your application automatically. You need to provide more detail in your question to understand why this is not working for you, such as the steps you took to create the repo and populate it with your Bluemix application. Generally it's good practice to create the git repo first. See this [Bluemix help topic](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/deploy_devops.html) for details.

To get a better response to your Stack Overflow questions, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)